# Calling contract invocation operation in loop

Tags: node, smart-contracts, conseil

I have some set of data which I am trying to push to my smart contract in loop. I use conseiljs to send data to smart contract.

Here is the code depicting what I am trying to do.

```
async function sendDataToContract(feedData,nodeAddress,publicKey,privateKey,keyHash,contractAddress) 
{
      const keystore = {
          publicKey: publicKey,
          privateKey: privateKey,
          publicKeyHash: keyHash,
          seed: '',
          storeType: conseiljs.StoreType.Fundraiser
      };
      for(let i=0;i<feedData.length;i++)
      {
        try 
        {
            const result = await conseiljs.TezosNodeWriter.sendContractInvocationOperation(nodeAddress, keystore, contractAddress,  0, 100000, '', 1000, 750000, undefined, `(Pair "${feedData[i].firstname} ${feedData[i].income}")`, conseiljs.TezosParameterFormat.Michelson);
            console.log(result.operationGroupID);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(" Catch Error : ",e.stack);
        }
      }
}

function sendData()
{
  sendDataToContract(feedData,nodeAddress,publicKey,privateKey,keyHash,contractAddress);
}
```

Catch Error:

```
Catch Error :  Error: (temporary: failure)
    at parseRPCError (F:\oro-latest\weather-oracle\node_modules\conseiljs\dist\chain\tezos\TezosNodeWriter.js:398:19)
    at F:\oro-latest\weather-oracle\node_modules\conseiljs\dist\chain\tezos\TezosNodeWriter.js:150:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (F:\oro-latest\weather-oracle\node_modules\conseiljs\dist\chain\tezos\TezosNodeWriter.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I cover this in my [Tezos workflows sample](https://gist.github.com/anonymoussprocket/148d82fc9bf6c413be04155a90d57be6). The issue is that a blockchain operation is not recorded immediately. You need to wait for it be included before proceeding with the next one. Insider the `try` in the `for` loop, you need something like this:

```
const conseilResult = await TezosConseilClient.awaitOperationConfirmation(conseilServer, conseilServer.network, groupid, 5, networkBlockTime);
```